# Recommended approach for Serialization of large amount of data

Tags: serialization

I want to maintain large amount of data in binary format through serialization. 
I explored little. I found possible approaches like:

1. Using externalization
2. Using GZipOutputStream
3. Using DataOutputStream instead of ObjectOutputStream.

Information objects are in ArrayList and List size is approx 1 lac. 
Please suggest best approach to write and read this much amount of data into/from file.

thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Serialization with an ObjectOutputStream first, it that doesnt work or it takes to long then i would try a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with data at that size, I'd suggest to use a database.